# what is the workaround for the kernel too old error in docker on centos

Tags: docker

I just started dockering and here hits my very first docker question.

I am using `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)`.

I need to build a docker image for JupyterHub, here is the JupyterHub image: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/, what I did is:

```
docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub
```

And then I ran:

```
sudo docker images
```

, I see the following:

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
jupyterhub/jupyterhub   latest              3726912b8cfc        5 months ago        811.5 MB
<none>                  <none>              7cdb3c49d61f        2 years ago         4.766 GB
```

What is the huge **none** repo that comes with an image id?
When I ran:

sudo docker run --name test 3726912b8cfc
I received:

> FATAL: kernel too old

What does it mean? and how to work around with it?

Comment: What is your kernel version? Docker requires 3.10 as a minimun.

Comment: Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1, yes I think that is too old.

Comment: Thats the docker version, you can see the kernel version with `uname -v`. RedHat backported some functionality to make docker work with their old kernels so make sure you are running their latest suported kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redhat pulled support for docker on el6 a long time ago. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1378023

The 1.7 version of Docker that is in those repositories hasn't received updates since the backport effort was pulled.

Modern Docker images tend to not be tested against old versions of Docker and they could require a newer kernel than centos 6 provides.

The upstream Docker project only provides packages for Centos 7 as of the time of writing of this answer (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#os-requirements)

> To install Docker CE, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7

Since 2017, running Docker on centos tends to require centos 7 instead of centos 6 for practical usecases.